# Assemble Release build failed after update React Native (to 0.59.10)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

After updating my react-native version from 0.58.0 to 0.59.10 I have problem with assemlbe release build.

1. `react-native run-ios` works
2. iOS build (on BuddyBuild) works
3. `react-native run-android` on simulator - works

But when I want to get release build and run command `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` - build failed.

I checked linking, but I think everything is linked properly.

I got this error:

```
> Task :react-native-fcm:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fcm:verifyReleaseResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  /Users/myname/Documents/projects/my-project/node_modules/react-native-fcm/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:1968: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/myname/Documents/projects/my-project/node_modules/react-native-fcm/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:1968: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

What I can do about this?

Comment: Have you added `ProGuard` rules?

Answer (score 0):

I updated `react-native-fcm` to version 16.0.0. After that I did this command:

```
rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/build && cd ios && pod install
```

And everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Hope so it will help